# AS3: Element stays on stage after manipulating the index(depth)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

After I change the index of one movieclip using

```
oldIndex = getChildIndex(DisplayObject(e.target));
setChildIndex(DisplayObject(e.target), numChildren - 1);
```

when I give the object its old index

```
setChildIndex(DisplayObject(e.target), oldIndex);
```

and go to another frame of the movie, this element I have changed the index of stays on top of all elements on the new frame.

My question is am I doing something wrong and if not, what can I do so that this element stays only in the frame it is placed?

Comment: could you elaborate more about your problem. Frames don't have nothing to do with levels. Remember that when you add a display object to the display list without defining the index it will be added on the top (the highest index available) then if you add it in a specific index it may reorder other display objects index.

Comment: the best is only to use frames when you cannot avoid it (as in transforming animations) and trying not to mix frames and ActionScript.

Comment: I have the objects on the stage (they are not loaded dynamically with AS) and if I try to set the index of such element and then gotoAndStop on another frame - this object appears also on the new frame (it's the same no matter if i swap indexes or just set new index). Maybe the problem is I have the object on the stage and then set the index using AS. What I did to fix it was to check if element exists on the new frame and delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you load a frame you reset the elements to the appearance they have in the frame. Either you need to stick to frame-based, or code-based animation, otherwise you need to create an array or such that contains the order of the objects, then every time you change the frame, scan the array and assign the objects to the relevent indexes.